# What do the + signs do in these DNS TXT records?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, txt-record

Is there a specific reason why some records contain the '+' sign and others do not?  Are these handled similar to a common search function where you can preface terms with + to include them, but it's usually redundant because they are included by default?

`v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:000.00.00.000 ~all`

`v=spf1 a mx ptr include:domain.com ~all`

Comment: Did you do *any* research on your own before posting here?  Like maybe looking at [the OpenSPF record specification](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax), which answers your question in the very first page?

Answer (score 3):

Those DNS TXT records are so-called SPF records, SPF being an email sender verification protocol known as [**S**ender **P**olicy **F**ramework](http://www.openspf.org/).

Each validation mechanism in SPF is (optionally) prefixed with one of the following qualifiers, indicating how a match on an inbound message should be treated:

- `+: Pass`
- `-: Fail`
- `~: SoftFail`
- `?: Neutral`

The default qualifier is always `+`, but some people like to be explicit.

Thus `+a` and `a` will be treated as exactly the same

Comment: Thanks, I figured they were treated the same, just looking for explicit confirmation.